# How can I replace < and > in the content of xml file using regex?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, regex, replace

How can i replace a "<" and a ">" (in the content of xml file) with a matching `"&lt;"` and `"&gt;"` 
(with a pre known set of tags) using a regex?

example: `<abc>fd<jkh</abc><def>e>e</def>` should result with: 
`<abc>fd&lt;jkh</abc><def>e&lt;e</def>`

it must be done with a regex! (no xml load and such...)

Comment: What do you want to do with `<abc def="g<h"><abc def="<ghi jkl=<mno>></abc><ghi><jkl<mno>`?

Comment: thanks for replying! i have no attributes in this file.

Comment: @Jack: But are there any CDATA section or comments?

Comment: no. there is no CDATA or comments

Comment: this is the example which will solve all the cases. "<abc>>sdfsdf<<asdada>>asdasd<>asdasd<asdsad>asds<</abc>" only the <abc> and the matching </abc> are predefined.

Comment: -1 The failure to specify that you wanted to replace `<` and `>` on enclosed tags like `<asdsad>` that don't have a matching closing tag caused us to waste time on this question, which is clearly out of bounds for a reasonable regex solution.

Comment: Don't do it with a regex. Regardless of your situation, you're going to run into trouble: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-rege

Answer (score 2):

I think the pattern

```
<([^>]*<)
```

will match a `<` that encounters another `<` before `>` (therefore not part of a tag)

...and the pattern

```
(>[^<]*)>
```

will match a `>` that follows another `>`

```
var first = Regex.Replace(@"<abc>fd<jkh</abc><def>e>e</def>",@"<([^>]*?<)",@"&lt;$1");
var final = Regex.Replace(first,@"(>[^<]*?)>",@"$1&gt;");
```

#### EDIT:

This does work, but you have to pass over it multiple times. I'm sure there's a purer method, but this does work.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var next = @"<abc>dffs<<df</abc>";
        string current;
        do
        {
            current = next;
            next = Regex.Replace(current, @"<([^>]*?<)", @"&lt;$1");
            next = Regex.Replace(next, @"(>[^<]*?)>", @"$1&gt;");
        } while(next != current);
        Console.WriteLine(current);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jack you didn't give <abc>dffs<<df</abc>  as an example.  I think you should learn some RegEx so that you can take Jay's example and expand it.  Remember we are supposed to point you down a path, not walk it for you.

Comment: this is my actual example, which will solve all the cases. "<abc>>sdfsdf<<asdada>>asdasd<>asdasd<asdsad>asds<</abc>" only the <abc> and the matching </abc> are predefined.

Comment: this one is very good! but still didn't work with replacing the <asdada> and <> !

Answer (score 0):

```
s/<(?=[^<>]*<)/&lt;/g
s/>(?<=\>[^<>]*)/&gt;/g
```

In C#,

```
new Regex("<(?=[^<>]*<)").Replace(your_xml_string, "&lt;");
new Regex(">(?<=\>[^<>]*)").Replace(your_xml_string, "&gt;");
```

Not tested. I don't have C# on my hand.

Comment: very good. but it didnt replace something like <abc>>dfddf</abc>
and also didn't replace the not predifined tags like
<abc>sdfsdf<job>dasf</abc>
there has to be some predefine tags... otherwise we don't get the replacement of the undefined tags...

Comment: @Jack: Why can't you write down all arguments at once in the question?  And you can't expect to use 1 or 2 simple regex if you need to detect `<x><y></x>`.