# replacing an undefined tags inside an xml string using a regex

Tags: c#, regex, replace, tags

i need to replace an undefined tags inside an xml string.

example: `<abc> <>sdfsd <dfsdf></abc><def><movie></def>` (only `<abc>` and `<def>` are defined)

should result with: `<abc> &lt;&gt;sdfsd &lt;dfsdf&gt;</abc><def>&lt;movie&gt;<def>`
`<>` and `<dfsdf>` are not predefined as  and  and does not have a closing tag.

it must be done with a regex!.
no using xml load and such.

i'm working with C# .Net

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134752/how-can-i-replace-and-in-the-content-of-xml-file-using-regex

Comment: Can there be whitespace in tags `< abc >`? Could there be CDATA regions? Could there be xml comments?

Comment: Don't do it using a regex. I know you said that you had to, but you're on a fool's errand. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-rege

Comment: Is this also a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097998?  It's like the same question over and over again.

Comment: no white spaces in tag. and yes. this is a subsolution of my old one. i have only this case solve which was not solved in my old question.

Comment: You just asked this question. -1

Comment: must be done with a regex... it's an old story. :)

Comment: @yodaj007, it's not quite a duplicate. Yes, they look a-like, but they're definitely different questions.

Comment: yes i asked for something which was more compilcated and i got the answers. but this specific case wasn't solved yet.

Comment: it's just a sub case from my last question

Comment: @Jack: you should probably include a link to your previous question and explain why it's different. Not only will it prevent erroneous closing, it also helps us because we can read the comments there and use that to improve our understanding of your needs, and perhaps get some ideas from the answers suggested there. Also the people there asked exactly the same questions as I did. Why not just include this information in the question in the first place instead of making us play "Guess The Requirements(TM)"?

Comment: Why must it be done with a regex? What sort of a regex? Are there any constraints on the sorts of regex you can use? Must the regex be run in a specific way or can we choose that ourselves? If the former, what way? How will you test our answers? Using a tool? Do you have a test case or framework that it must run in? Can you post the code you will be using to test our answers? Please tell us **all** your requirements, especially if they are going to break the obvious solutions.

Comment: Hi Mark, you are right... i'm so hasty sometimes... the help that you gave me was very helpful. i hope to do these things better in the future in order to get the best help and to help others. next time i will improve my needs but i didn't want it to be too complicated because i didn't want to bother too much others valuable time. actually my file is in SGML and i have alot of troubles with it. because there are some errors inside. but you have solve my last, most hardest problem. thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
    string s = "<abc> <>sdfsd <dfsdf></abc><def><movie></def>";
    string regex = "<(?!/?(?:abc|def)>)|(?<!</?(?:abc|def))>";
    string result = Regex.Replace(s, regex, match =>
    {
        if (match.Value == "<")
            return "&lt;";
        else
            return "&gt;";
    });
    Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Result:

```
<abc> &lt;&gt;sdfsd &lt;dfsdf&gt;</abc><def>&lt;movie&gt;</def>
```

Also, when tested on your other test case (which by the way I found in a comment on the other question):

```
<abc>>sdfsdf<<asdada>>asdasd<>asdasd<asdsad>asds<</abc>
```

I get this result:

```
<abc>&gt;sdfsdf&lt;&lt;asdada&gt;&gt;asdasd&lt;&gt;asdasd&lt;asdsad&gt;asds&lt;</abc>
```

Let me guess... this doesn't work for you because you just thought of a new requirement? ;)

Comment: no....no new requierments. i'm so sorry for the bothering :) won't do it next time :)

Comment: @Jack: Well you got what you wanted, that's the important thing. Just remember that the sort of answers you get depend on the quality of the question, so if you spend a bit longer making the question more precise you probably won't have to wait so long to get an answer you can use. We don't need several pages of details, but there are a few key details that you really need to give, because without those details we don't have a chance of getting the answer right. There was not enough information in this question to produce this answer - I only got it because I read your other question too.

Answer (score 1):

> it must be done with a regex! no using xml load and such.

I must hammer this nail in with my boot! No using a hammer and such. It's an old story :)

You'll need to supply more information. Are "valid" tags allowed to be nested? Are the "valid" tags likely to change at any point? How robust does this need to be?

Assuming that your list of valid tags isn't going to change at any point, you could do it with a regex substitution:

```
s/<(?!\/?(your|valid|tags))([^>]*)>/&lt;$1&gt;/g
```

Comment: While this looks like it will work fine according to the requirements he gave, unfortunately I suspect it's not what he wants because if you read his other question he wrote a comment: `this is my actual example, which will solve all the cases. "<abc>>sdfsdf<<asdada>>asdasd<>asdasd<asdsad>asds<</abc>"` and I guess your answer will fail for this example (haven't tested it though).